# Java - Unable to launch the application

Tags: java, launch

I can't seem to launch a .jar file. An error comes up when I launch it. Help would be appreciated, here is the error:

```
    CouldNotLoadArgumentException[ Could not load file/URL specified: C:\Users\Donavon\AppData\Local\Temp\javaws12]
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, please check if your TEMP folder is still there.

Second, if you can find jawaaws12 in there, move it to somewhere else. Then uninstall and re-install java. The appropriate file should be created automatically.

Comment: A couple days ago I was messing around with my local folder, I can recalling deleting the Temp folder, which I'm almost sure it contained my files needed in the error code.

Comment: So problem solved? If yes, you can upvote and accept this answer so that people who have similar issues can take reference.

Comment: No, problem isn't solved. My Temp folder is gone, I permanently deleted it. I'm not sure what I should do to get it back.